# Why I cant import the library that in swift file after installing the the dependency in Cocoapods?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I already install this library, [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip) via Cocoapod. My pod file is look like this,and already hit `pod install` in terminal.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyProject' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyProject
  pod 'XLPagerTabStrip', '~> 8.0'

end
```

So everything is completed install,but when I want to import the library in Swift file,it giving an error ->> **No such module 'XLPagerTabSript'.**

I read a lot of question about this,which mention add the file path of the library to 
***Build Setting -> Search Paths -> User Header Search Paths***. I also already did,but still giving the same error.

**What I add in *User Header Search Path* is something like this:**

> ${SRCROOT}/Users/Myname/Desktop/MyProject/Pods/XLPagerTabStrip

After adding the file path,I clean the project,build the project again,the tried to add in `import XLPagerTabStrip` to one of my swift file,the error still the same.

Can somebody let me know what is problem actually? Cause I beginner in Ios development,I totally no idea what I doing wrong.

Comment: Can you clean your derived data, clean the build folder etc... Xcode tends to be painful while indexing etc...Just clean, and restart and try to use your newly added framework.

Comment: clean my derived data??where is derived data??cause I new in swift,I come from Android background,so this is very painful me..haha

Comment: Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> small arrow near derived data. Close Xcode and delete all folders in the Derived data folder from Finder.

Comment: hey bro,I deleted all the derived data,clean the project,but still cant import..once I type in import XLPagerTabScript,it show no module exists

Comment: Is i only pod you have in your Podfile ?

Comment: Did you open the xcworkspace file instead of the xcodeproj file ?

Comment: ya,,I open  xcworkspace file @CZ54

Comment: @mihatel ya..I only add in 1 pod

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate 
try to deintegrate pod and install it again, once it helped me out for similar issue

Comment: @mihatel let me try and let you know..

Comment: @mihatel I deintergrate the pod,I even open a new project and install the pod from start,it still cant be done..Once I `import XLPagerTabScript` it still "No module found"

Comment: @ken: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sa5k0y35rij8qb4/XLPagerTabScriptDemo.zip?dl=0
I've created demo it is ok for me, please download and run. Meanwhile you can check your pod version, if it is too old you can try to update it

Comment: ok thanks bro..I will try it now

Comment: @mihatel I download your project the project cannot be open..normally how people install dependencies?why it is so hard to do this??

Comment: @ken: I didn't get what you mean by "the project cannot be open..normally", can you please provide your sources

Comment: @mihatel I mean the project u send me at dowpbox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160068/discussion-between-mihatel-and-ken).

Comment: @mihatel thank you,you are right..problem is cause by my Xcode version.thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up solve it by update my Xcode vesion and insert the file path of the library in inside

> Build Setting -> Search Paths -> Framework Search Paths -> (Add the
>   file path of the library here)

By this I can import the library in swift file without any warning